# Hosting and delivering videos on a Node.js (Express.js) dedicated server

Tags: video, server, hosting

I live in a country where we have a global and a national "internet" which is way faster than the global one.

Although our "national" internet has very few to no modern solutions for hosting and deploying web applications, there are services that give you virtual and dedicated servers.

So, for our educational website which uses video as its primary content, we have to use a dedicated server to host and deploy website, so the video delivery is fast.

I've never ever worked with video hosting. If there are any solutions, things to study, any other kind of recommendation, that would make a huge impact for an easier and less money-wasteful start.

I'd really appreaciate for any kind of libraries, frameworks, references that may help develop a video-hosting platform.

Thank you.

P.S.: the problem here is more an architecture. How to scale an app? Is storing videos in a "videos" directory and storing links in the DB a scalable solution? Is there any kind of scalable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Look for an open source project. You don't need to write it by yourself.

Check [this](https://mediadrop.video/) for example.

Anyway you should ask this question on ServerFault.